# Adding a referrer variable within a WordPress post

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress is it possible to include a referrer variable in the body of a post so that the url of the visitor's entry point is generated when the post is served? The purpose is to generate a tracking string for visitors to use if they want to re-post an article on their web site. Specifically, a user clicks on a link that says "repost this article on your blog" which then takes them to a terms of use page that includes this language:

> If you'd like to use this post on your web site, please credit the
>   author and include a link back to the specific article URL (in this
>   case: www.mysite.com/[URL-of-article-to-be-resposted]).

[URL-of-article-to-be-resposted] would be the post from which they came to the terms of service page.

PHP variables like  and  don't seem to work within the WP post. Is there a variable that handles this?

I apologize if this is a newbie question -- I'm new to WP, coming from old school html where I could use a serve-side-include to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe add_query_arg function will serve your purpose.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/

Please read the developer doc thoroughly.

I hope this'll help.